# Python - how to load nested dictionary into Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, nested

I have a long nested dictionary structured like below, how can I go about loading this into a Pandas dataframe? The sub keys of `Feed`, `Spindle Speed`, and `Tool` remain the same throughout, but the two levels above (`Heading`, `N1`, etc and `4001`, `4002` etc are unique or at least in unique orders throughout the dictionary.

I'm aware of something like this:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict({(i,j): dictionary[i][j] 
                           for i in dictionary.keys() 
                           for j in dictionary[i].keys()},
                       orient='index')
```

But this looks like a pivot table, where I'd prefer a data frame with the redundant information (liek `4001`) to run down the entire column.

```
{
    "4001": {
        "Heading": {
            "Feed": [],
            "Spindle Speed": [],
            "Tool": []
        },
        "N1": {
            "Feed": [],
            "Spindle Speed": [],
            "Tool": [
                "0800"
            ]
        },
        "N10 ": {
            "Feed": [
                0.01,
                0.0006,
                0.0001,
                0.0006,
                0.0001,
                0.0006,
                0.0002,
                0.02,
                0.0004
            ],
            "Spindle Speed": [
                "M3S2630"
            ],
            "Tool": [
                "1616"
            ]
        }
    },
    "4002": {
        "Heading": {
            "Feed": [],
            "Spindle Speed": [],
            "Tool": []
        },
        "N1": {
            "Feed": [],
            "Spindle Speed": [],
            "Tool": [
                "9900"
            ]
        },
        "N10": {
            "Feed": [
                0.01,
                0.001,
                0.0004,
                0.001,
                0.005
            ],
            "Spindle Speed": [],
            "Tool": [
                "3838"
            ]
        }
    },     
    "4003": {...
             ...
             ...
```

The dataframe would look something like this ideally:

```
Program Operation Number    Feed        Tool      Spindle Speed
4001    Heading             []          []        []
4001    N1                  []          ['0800']  []
4001    N10                 [0.01, ...] ['1616']  ['M3S2630']
```

Comment: What would you like the dataframe to look like (title and content of columns, content of row)?

Comment: And... what about `df.reset_index()`?

Comment: I've updated my question with a desired "look" of the `df`. Thank you for asking. I'm unsure what you mean by what about `reset_index()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there. You have just to reset the multi_index and give the correct column names:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict({(i,j): dictionary[i][j] 
                           for i in dictionary.keys() 
                           for j in dictionary[i].keys()},
                       orient='index').reset_index().rename(
    {'level_0': 'Program', 'level_1': 'Operation Number'}, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Run this line of code after importing pandas to configure your dataframes to not be "sparse":

```
pd.set_option('display.multi_sparse', False)
```

From [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html):

> Option: display.multi_sparse
>   Default: True
>   Function: “Sparsify” MultiIndex display (don’t display repeated elements in outer levels within groups)

Output using first two groupings you provided:

[image]