# How to create dataframe and set index with dictionary of dictionaries?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, nested

I want to create a Dataframe with the columns as the Days of the week, and each person's name and corresponding start/end times. So far I can get the data from the dictionary to the Dataframe, but I am struggling to get the index correct. I managed to get a bit of help from this question [Python - how to load nested dictionary into Pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56170853/python-how-to-load-nested-dictionary-into-pandas-dataframe), but I'm not sure how to rearange the indexes to achieve what I need.

I know I need to `.drop` the `Times` column altogether, but after that I am coming up short of ideas. I'm thinking somehow set `row[0]` as the index, but I'm unsure if that would be the best way to do this.

Here's what I've got working so far:

data:

```
employees = {"Mon":{
                "Name":{"0":"John","1":"Nick","2":"Ali","3":"Joseph"},
                "Start":{"0":"9a","1":"9a","2":"3p","3":"3p"},
                "End":{"0":"5p","1":"5p","2":"11p","3":"11p"},
            },
            "Tues":{
                "Name":{"0":"John","1":"Nick","2":"Ali","3":"Joseph"},
                "Start":{"0":"9a","1":"9a","2":"3p","3":"3p"},
                "End":{"0":"5p","1":"5p","2":"11p","3":"11p"},
        }
}
```

code to create the dataframe:

```
dict_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({(i,j): employees[i][j]
                                      for i in employees.keys()
                                      for j in employees[i].keys()}, orient='index').reset_index().rename(
{'level_0': 'Day', 'level_1': 'Name'}, axis=1)
```

current output:

```
    Day   Name     0     1    2       3
0   Mon   Name  John  Nick  Ali  Joseph
1   Mon  Start    9a    9a   3p      3p
2   Mon    End    5p    5p  11p     11p
3  Tues   Name  John  Nick  Ali  Joseph
4  Tues  Start    9a    9a   3p      3p
5  Tues    End    5p    5p  11p     11p
```

required output:

```
   Days  Times  John  Nick  Ali  Joseph
0   Mon  Start    9a    9a   3p      3p
1   Mon    End    5p    5p  11p     11p
2  Tues  Start    9a    9a   3p      3p
3  Tues    End    5p    5p  11p     11p
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a column equivalent to `set_index`, so you can create a DataFrame from each sub-dictionary and then Transpose and `concat` them together in the end. You can then assign the key as the day value.

In the end if you want a MultiIndex just `.set_index(['Days', 'Times'])`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.concat([(pd.DataFrame(d).set_index('Name').T
                   .rename_axis(index='Times', columns=None)
                   .reset_index()
                   .assign(Days=day))
                for day,d in employees.items()], ignore_index=True)
```

---

```
print(df)

   Times John Nick  Ali Joseph  Days
0  Start   9a   9a   3p     3p   Mon
1    End   5p   5p  11p    11p   Mon
2  Start   9a   9a   3p     3p  Tues
3    End   5p   5p  11p    11p  Tues
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks!